# sudo pip list: OpenSSL issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, openssl, debian

If I try one of the following commands:

- `sudo pip list`
- `sudo pip uninstall <something>`

I always get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/list.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import IndexGroupCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 48, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl import backend as openssl_backend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 75, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 205, in <module>
    _verify_openssl_version(Binding.lib)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 169, in _verify_openssl_version
    "You are linking against OpenSSL 1.0.1, which is no longer "
RuntimeError: You are linking against OpenSSL 1.0.1, which is no longer supported by the OpenSSL project. You need to upgrade to a newer version of OpenSSL.
```

**The error is pretty clear, I know!** What's unclear is:

- Why can't I just *list* my installed packages? OpenSSL error... with pip list?! What does OpenSSL have to do with the list of installed packages?! I just want to see what's installed on my server
- Why can't I just *uninstall* a package? Again, what does OpenSSL have to do with it?
- I have a server **identical** to the server with this problem (Debian 7, same OpenSSL version, same Python version) but on the other server everything works without problems (there isn't even a warning)

Additional info:

- Python version: Python 2.7.3
- OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7

Comment: go to that files, and remove the error message. You are uninstalling stuff, so you do not care about functionality. And i would recommend not to use `pip` with `sudo`. For root (and system use standard tools), use pip just for specific users, or in specific virtual environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python packaging is "fun". Let's go on an adventure!

`pip` vendors `urllib3`, which [automatically uses pyOpenSSL](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/50aca38eafde71ac0314d14246f7ebf043695f5e/src/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py#L107) if it is present on Python < 2.7.9. This is done because Python < 2.7.9 does not support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) in TLS; a critical modern feature. `pyOpenSSL`, in turn, depends on `cryptography`, which dropped 1.0.1 support in version 2.9. So when you attempt to do anything in `pip` it triggers an import sequence that results in this error.

The (likely) reason that you don't see this problem on another nearly identical server is that `cryptography` also ships binary wheels that statically link newer OpenSSLs. If you are on pip 8.x or better (which you likely were on the server that works and likely were **not** on the server that is broken) it will fetch a wheel linked against OpenSSL 1.1.1-latest (provided you're on x86_64. i686 wheels were dropped in 2.7).

Given the error message you're seeing you're almost certainly running cryptography 2.9.x on the broken server. That version [supports an environment variable](https://cryptography.io/en/2.9.2/faq/#importing-cryptography-causes-a-runtimeerror-about-openssl-1-0-1) workaround. So if you do `CRYPTOGRAPHY_ALLOW_OPENSSL_101=1 pip list` it should work.

If that works then you should immediately upgrade `cryptography`. Since you're now running pip 20.x on this server the command `CRYPTOGRAPHY_ALLOW_OPENSSL_101=1 pip install -U cryptography` should install version 3.1 from a wheel (assuming you're running on x86_64).

If you are **not** running on x86_64 then you have two options (that don't involve upgrading your distribution, which you should since wheezy is long out of support!):

1. Always pass `CRYPTOGRAPHY_ALLOW_OPENSSL_101` and never upgrade `cryptography` again (2.9.2 being the last version that even secretly supports 1.0.1)
2. Downgrade `cryptography` to 2.8 and also never upgrade it again.

Comment: It is exactly as you said, now I can solve my problem (the building wheel for cryptography actually fails but it is another problem). Thank you so much - really! - for using your time to help me. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: EDIT: my fault, I'm on a i686 CPU, it's normal that the building wheel for cryptography fails, thanks again